# Android widget, how to use notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged in Android API <11

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider

I want to update my widget in order to became compatible for Android 2.3.3 (API 10).

I have some problem in my code.

The following methods are not recognize with minsdkversion = 10.

How can i replace them in my APPwidgetProvider class, in order to use my widget with Android 2.3.3, 3.0 .... 4.0 ?

```
rv.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.stack_view, intent);
rv.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_view, R.id.empty_view);
rv.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_view, toastPendingIntent);
appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(i, R.id.stack_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection view was introduced from API 11, so you can't use your stack view.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections